# CSS Font Loss of detail

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

This is my first time using detail fonts but for some reason it loses all of its detail.

Expected result:

[image: A font with fine detail]

Actual result:

[image: A font missing the fine details in the expected result]

```css
footer h3 {
  font-family: "Elegance";
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Elegance";
  src: url("../fonts/GeraldinePersonalUseItalic-PK12m.ttf");
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h3>Greetings</h3>
</footer>
```

Comment: How are ou setting up the font family. lease create a working snippet which shows the problem.

Comment: Is that font publicly available? I don't think we can really help with this without seeing the problem in action, and right now your example doesn't work as the font is missing.

Comment: What sort of license have you got on that font?

Comment: Might be anti-aliasing setting that renders it thicker. Also, aside from the technical implementation, your `font-size` is `50px` and it won't be realistic to expect all those fine details show up in limited 50 pixels of space. Such display fonts are typically better reserved as large _display_ type. Also, I'd recommend sticking to web-optimized font files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have your font weight set to bold in your CSS somewhere.

I was able to reproduce this issue by setting my font-weight to bold.

Try changing it to normal/400 and see if that fixes it.

[image: Screen shot of reproduced issue]

Comment: Thanks ! It was inheriting 200 from the body. It's always the simplest fixes